# Is Discord User Id too big to send dm too?

Tags: discord, bots, pycord

I'm making a slash command that can send dms to a specific user id that's been determined by a command argument. It works for specific user ids, but not all of them, including mine my alt account. Is it some permission thing or is the user id out of range?

My code

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# importing environmental vars
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
GUILD = os.getenv("DISCORD_GUILD")
APP_ID = os.getenv("APP_ID")
PUB_KEY = os.getenv("PUBLIC_KEY")
GUILD_ID = os.getenv("GUILD_ID")
GENERAL_CHAN_ID = os.getenv("CHANNEL_GENERAL_ID")
#finished importing .env vars

intents = discord.Intents.all()
activity = discord.Activity(name="being awesome losers", type = discord.ActivityType.streaming)

bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents, activity=activity)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {bot.user}")

@bot.slash_command(description="sends message to someone still testing",guild_ids=[GUILD_ID])
async def send_message(ctx, user_id: str, message: str):
    user = bot.get_user(int(user_id))
    await user.send(message)
    await ctx.respond("Message sent successfully!", ephemeral = True)
    
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(956302622170701946)
    if message.content.startswith("help"):
        await message.author.send('')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

When I input an ID that doesn't work it gives me this traceback

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rayan\source\repos\DBot\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 124, in wrapped     
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "C:\Users\Rayan\source\repos\DBot\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 980, in _invoke     
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Rayan\source\repos\DBot\main.py", line 56, in send_message
    await user.send(message)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the issue is that the ID is out of range. It's simply that the user is not in the cache.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# importing environmental vars
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
GUILD = os.getenv("DISCORD_GUILD")
APP_ID = os.getenv("APP_ID")
PUB_KEY = os.getenv("PUBLIC_KEY")
GUILD_ID = os.getenv("GUILD_ID")
GENERAL_CHAN_ID = os.getenv("CHANNEL_GENERAL_ID")
#finished importing .env vars

intents = discord.Intents.all()
activity = discord.Activity(name="being awesome losers", type = discord.ActivityType.streaming)

bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents, activity=activity)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {bot.user}")

@bot.slash_command(description="sends message to someone still testing",guild_ids=[GUILD_ID])
async def send_message(ctx, user_id: str, message: str):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(int(user_id))
    await user.send(message)
    await ctx.respond("Message sent successfully!", ephemeral = True)
    
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(956302622170701946)
    if message.content.startswith("help"):
        await message.author.send('')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

This will always fetch the user and therefore will be able to DM everyone, even not in the cache.